# Retrieve Video thumbnail images from firebase storage in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, storage

I upload the video in Firebase store successfully. I would like to be able to do one of the following:

- I want to create thumbnail programmatically when I upload the video, or
- I want to show video thumbnail when I retrieve the video from Firebase storage.

I can retrieve video title and description or images** successfully  using `RecyclerAdapter`, but when I try to retrieve the video using Glide `asGif()`, it show nothing.

```
Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(videoUrl).into(imgView);
```

Comment: Firebase has rules. To use Glide, you will have to make sure the rule for the video file you trying to download is readable to everyone

Answer (score 3):

This code work to show thumbnail in firebase Storage using Glide

```
long interval = getPosition()*1000;   
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions().frame(interval);  

Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(baseuri).apply(options).into(imgView);
```

Thanks all for Response.

Comment: if anybody has a question what getPostion() is then you can just omit getpostion(). It will have no effect.